# Range of $(x+\sqrt{x})(10-x+\sqrt{10-x})$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

I was evaluating the range of this function in real numbers:

$f(x)=(x+\sqrt x)(10-x+\sqrt {10-x})$

It can be seen that the maximum occurs at $x=5$, but I couldn't find a neat way to prove it! Give it a shot!

Comment: Use $$x=10\sin^2y$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That is ingenious.

Comment: I have already tried that one, It seems that there are no good results after simplifying.

Comment: Another way: $$4ab$$ will be maximum($(a+b)^2$) if $a=b$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How to apply this method to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that the domain of $f(x)$ is $\{x|x \in \mathbb{R^+} \land 0 \le x \le 10\}$ 
 and that $$f'(x)=(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}})(10-x+\sqrt{10-x})-(x+\sqrt{x})(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{10-x}})$$
$$=10-x+\sqrt{10-x}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(10-x+\sqrt{10-x})-x-\sqrt{x}-\frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{10-x}}$$

If you solve for $f'(x)=0$, you will get $x=5$ and $f''(5)<0$. So you will be able to show that $$f'(x)=\begin{cases} +ve & 0\le x<5 \\ -ve &  5<x\le 10\end{cases}$$

And $f(0)=f(10)=0$

So range is $\{x|x \in \mathbb{R^+} \land 0 \le x \le 5\}$

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily seen that there is a local extremum at $x=5$ because the function is symmetric around the point $x=5$:
$$ f(10-x) = f(x) $$
It is because the function is explicitly written as a product of the two "mirror" factors
$$ f(x) = g(x) g(10-x)$$
where
$$ g(x) = x+ \sqrt{x} $$
Because the function doesn't have any extremely pathological singularity at $x=5$, there must be a local extremum over there.

Comment: Is this proves that maximum occurs at x=5? because you have said that we have a local extremum at x=5 and not the absolute maximum!

Comment: You need to run a few more arguments. First, the function $f(x)$ is only well-defined for $0\leq x \leq 10$. Second, the factor $g(x)$ is an increasing function for $0\leq x \leq 10$ and relatively speaking, it is more quickly increasing (percentage per unit $x$) than it is for a higher $x$, or, equivalently,than $g(10-x)$. So between $0$ and $5$, $f(x)$ inherits the increasing character from $g(x)$. ... You may always verify that there are no other local extrema between $0,10$ (by setting $f'(x)=0$) and you may verify that the second derivative $f''(5)\lt 0$ which proves it is a maximum.

Comment: Just to be sure, if you draw a graph of $f(x)$, it is a boring quasi-parabolic bump between $x=0$ and $x=10$, having $f=0$ for $x=0$ and $x=10$, the boundaries, and reaching something like $f\approx 52.36$ for $x=5$.